# Как добавить hr после каждой p?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, dom

```html
<article>
        <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
        <p>First</p>
        <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
        <p>Second</p>
        <h3>Why do we use it?</h3>
        <p>Third</p>
</article>
```

Необходимо с помощью JavaScript вставить после каждого тега p тег hr, для визуального отделения абзацев друг от друга. Нельзя модифицировать указанную разметку, надо только написать script с кодом.

Что можно сделать? Какой использовать метод DOM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach((elem) => {
    elem.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<hr/>');
});
```

```html
<article>
    <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
    <p>First</p>
    <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
    <p>Second</p>
    <h3>Why do we use it?</h3>
    <p>Third</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 8):

Зачем здесь jquery, так то проще ;)

Pure HTML&CSS:

```css
p{
    margin: 3px 0px; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
    <p>First</p>
    <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
    <p>Second</p>
    <h3>Why do we use it?</h3>
    <p>Third</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 6):

А можно использовать ещё псевдоэлемент `::after`

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
  <p>First</p>
  <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
  <p>Second</p>
  <h3>Why do we use it?</h3>
  <p>Third</p>
</article>
```